# How to change linux default task scheduler?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

I want to compare the performance of the EAS scheduler with other task schedulers. As far as I understood from the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/index.html), there are several schedulers in the kernel, and at a certain point in time, one scheduler can be selected by the kernel, which is responsible for distributing all tasks among the processor's cores.

I have Xiaomi Redmi 9A with Android 10 and kernel version 4.9.190. The default task scheduler is EAS, but I want to try installing another scheduler (regular CFS, for example, or some custom one). I suspect that this requires patching the sources and recompiling the kernel, but I can't find any information on which configuration files I need to change and how to get the desired scheduler to be used in the compiled kernel. But maybe I'm wrong and there is another way to change the current scheduler at runtime through the kernel api. (Yes, I have read about sched_setscheduler, and from the description, this is not what I need. I need to change the scheduler to which all created threads are assigned by default.)

In any case, I would appreciate any information about switching schedulers. And about the schedulers themselves, because I'm not sure that I understood the principle of their work correctly. (After 2 months of googling, I realized that my skills were failing me, which brought me here)

Comment: EAS is not a scheduler per se, it's just a property of the scheduler. EAS does not replace CFS, your phone *is* running CFS, but with EAS the scheduling decisions aren't just based on time consumed by tasks (as in vanilla CFS) and also take energy consumption into account. Disabling EAS would just degrade the performance of your phone.

Comment: Make a copy of the `kernel/sched` directory to `kernel/mysched`.  Change `kernel/Makefile` to point to it.  Start hacking.

Comment: *"I would appreciate any information about switching schedulers"* -- Except for I/O schedulers, AFAICT there are no (build) configuration choices for anything besides the  *"default"* process scheduler in v5.x, i.e. see **kernel/sched/Makefile**.  However you can change the scheduling *policy*, and assign (process) groups.  IOW you seem to be confusing the various scheduling *policies* for *"several schedulers in the kernel,"*